# Plugin : Best way to safe a file in a project structure?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, path

I have written a small Java plugin in IntellIJ IDEA. This plugin allows me to create a yaml file.

I want to save it in my project structure using the [doOKAction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/ui/DialogWrapper.java) function.

If I hard code the path, it will work. But if I run my plugin on another computer it will not work. (Of course)

I would use:

```
Path root = Paths.get(".").normalize().toAbsolutePath();
```

but this isn't working...

Because the plugin is not included in the current project structure and i would get something like this :

```
"C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jetbrains.intellij.idea\ideaIC\2019.3.2\b911671d7501d9fd63cea3eee8287d8ceb4113c6\ideaIC-2019.3.2\bin ..."
```

If there is a way at all, what would be the best way to store a file somewhere in the project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_model/project.html on how to obtain paths in current Project structure setp.